# Will leaking valve seals harm an engine?

Tags: oil, valve

I have a Nissan VK45DE engine with some oil consumption issues that I think are leaking valve seals.

What harm will come to an engine if used long term with leaking valve seals other than the increase in oil consumption?

Comment: Eventually it will destroy the catalytic converter and possibly the 02 sensors, not cheap.

Comment: Well, cats already fell out, so it looks like that already happen, how does it damage the O2 sensors?,

Comment: excessive carbon deposits on the sensor

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the seals on the valve stems, basically the only factor is burning oil. I had a 1994 GMC Sonoma with the Vortec V 6 engine. Cheap rubber "O" rings on the valve stems failed at 50 K miles . I sold the truck when it had about 100 K miles and I know the subsequent owner drove many more miles without replacing the valve seals.  Oil consumption was not much , but there was a big puff of blue smoke on each start caused by the oil that ran down the stems when the engine was off.

Comment: Ok, I don't have oil smoke at start unless I have been pushing hard and high rpm engine braking then stopping the engine and leaving it for a couple of hours.  And smoke when I back off the throttle after accelerating hard (like at a strip)

Comment: Can't this also damage the catalytic converter and oxygen sensors?